# Manage revisions non-native files

Tags: google-drive-api

The manage revisions function is no longer available for non-native documents in the new Drive UI.

Can anyone tell me if

1. This feature will become available in the future, and
2. If it will still be possible to manage revisions for non-native documents via the Drive API?